# Get the message, whenever I try to refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have one web page with Model Pop-up.

Without any submit when I close this pop-up and Refresh page, Browser give me message like this...

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**FIREFOX message**

[image]

**GOOGLE CHROME message**

[image]

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

and if I click on Resend or Continue button, browser again give me my Model Pop-Up.

How can I fix this problem??

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

This is my code for display Pop-up

```
protected void applynow_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    pa1.Visible = true;   
    mo1.Show();
}
```

Comment: It is likely that your page has performed a post in order to load the popup.

Comment: Rather than the page you're on doing a postback to display the popup, it sounds like you had to do a postback to get to the page with the popup. So when you refresh the page, it asks to resend the post data that was originally sent to view the page. All of this has no relation to the popup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop unwanted postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437273/how-to-stop-unwanted-postback)

Comment: @TimBJames: I read this but it's not give a proper instruction, that's why I ask question privately.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811368/returning-to-that-page-might-cause-any-action-you-took-to-be-repeated-django http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775938/refresh-page-in-browser-without-resubmitting-form

Answer (score -1):

to prevent an unwanted POST while refreshing your page after a previous POST, use Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) pattern. after posting your page send a 302/303 response to your client browser and ask it redirect and initiate a get request.